# background-color can't hide button input

Tags: html, css

I gave my div some `background-color` property in my stylesheet.

```
.suggest_page {
    position: absolute; // it is gonna come on my button input 
    background-color: #ccffcc;
}
```

When it comes to on a button, button is showing up. I don't want this. I want `background-color` spread all place. What can I do?

**Note:** I can disable the button but I don't want to do this.

Comment: HTML? also provide a working jsfiddle.net example please

Comment: Sounds like a z-index issue. But as @BeNdErR said, we need example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `z-index` to your html style that you want to cover, or you could do the opposite and add it to the button, for example

**Style**

```
.suggest_page {
    position: absolute; // it is gonna come on my button input 
    background-color: #ccffcc;
    z-index:2; /*Has to be greater than what your button is */
}
```

Or **your Button**

```
#Button {
    z-index:-1; /* Has to be less than your suggest_page */
}
```